# how to set Lookless Custom Control Background?

Tags: wpf

I have a custom look less control. I created a Style and set the dependency properties in the style.

How do I set the background of the control in the template. Can I do this without explicitly declaring a dependency property?

```
public class AddressCustomControl:Control
{
   static AddressCustomControl()
   {
       DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(AddressCustomControl), new ....)
   }

  // Few dependency properties here...

}
```

Then I have the layout defined in Generic.xaml in the themes folder and specified targettype of the above control.

Everything is good as for data binding to the control.

Not I want the color of this control and few other properties like font, and fore color to be changed while using the control.

When I specify in the xaml like this nothing happens:

```
<local:AddressCustomControl Address={Binding BillAddress} Background="Silver" /> // Background does not change when I do this.
```

What am I missing here? May be I have to do something in my style?

This is my style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type controls:AddressCustomControl}">
      <Setter Property="Template">... setter value and the control template here...          </Setter.Value> // May be I need to do something here that I am missing?
</Style>
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Generic.xaml file you should set something like this on the control

```
Background={TemplateBinding Background}
```

For additional info check out this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084.aspx), under the section "preserving the functionality of a control's properites using templatebinding."